# Cannot resolve methods whilst using ML Kit in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

So I am using ML Kit for Image Labeling in an Android Studio project. This is my first time and so my friend provided me with the code. I am trying to make use of the Google Cloud Platform to get better results but I'm facing some problems. I'm getting two errors while trying to use ".setModelType(FirebaseVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions.LATEST_MODEL)".

Here is my code for cloud:

```
    case R.id.cloud:
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                MyHelper.showDialog(this);
                FirebaseVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions options = new FirebaseVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions.Builder()
                        .setModelType(FirebaseVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions.LATEST_MODEL)
                        .setMaxResults(5)
                        .build();

                FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(mBitmap);
                FirebaseVisionImageLabeler detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getCloudImageLabeler(options);
                detector.processImage(image).addOnSuccessListener(labels -> {
                    MyHelper.dismissDialog();
                    for (FirebaseVisionImageLabel label : labels) {
                        mTextView.append(label.getText() + ": " + label.getConfidence() + "\n\n");
                        mTextView.append(label.getEntityId() + "\n");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        MyHelper.dismissDialog();
                        mTextView.setText(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
    }
```

If anyone knows how to resolve this please do respond. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to follow the steps 1 ~ 5 in the following link (i.e. add the right dependencies):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/label-images